# Pain Dice in "Don't Rest Your Head"

Tags: dont-rest-your-head

In the game "Don't Rest Your Head" the flavor of a success or failure of a PC's action is determined by which dice pool has more 6's in it.  The PC has Exhaustion, Madness and Discipline dice, while the GM has only Pain dice. Since the number of Pain dice rolled is usually the largest, that means that the majority of all player actions cause them pain (whatever that might mean for a given character) as well as generating Despair Coins for the GM.

I think that the consequence of this would be an inevitable downward spiral for the players since the majority of all actions (even when the PC wins the contest) have a "Pain" flavor and generate more opportunities for the GM to thwart the players (Despair Coins).

Is there something I'm missing here, or is this just a game where the PCs are doomed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mitigating Factors

DRYH is not a game where the PCs are destined to lose, like Grey Ranks or Polaris (Arthurian ice elf edition), but it is a game where they begin as largely complete characters with dangerous things to accomplish and don't necessarily expect to win.

Here are some things you might be overlooking.

### Pain Dice are the only way the GM "acts".

The GM doesn't ever roll dice on their own to present a threat to the PCs or decide something bad has happened. The PCs are the ones taking action - Pain Dice show up as the opposition to it. So on that front, sure, Pain Dice should dominate at least sometimes, otherwise why even have them?

### Pain Dice don't begin in large numbers.

Yes, Mother When is Pain 12, but Mother When came screaming out of a doorway between madness and oblivion and might be Death? PCs don't start out staring down the barrel of Mother When.

> When determining the level of pain, keep in mind that the best a character can do safely (i.e. just using discipline) is get three successes, so *any* pain rating above three is reasonably significant - and any rating above six demands, due to the average number of successes (more than three), that the character move into risky territory. (Pain, p. 17)

3 Pain is a good average figure for "madness minion", and 5 is "madness lieutenant". (Creating New Nightmares, p. 70) Neither of these are more Exhaustion or Madness dice than PCs can bring to the table. Though, uh, they probably shouldn't.

### A success where Pain dominates is still a success.

When a PC succeeds but Pain dominates, that PC hasn't somehow failed to do what they were trying to do. There's fallout, sure, unintended consequences, but things shouldn't get absolutely worse.

### Hope only comes from Despair.

Yes, the GM gets Despair when Pain dominates, but the only way for PCs to get Hope to recover from exhaustion or madness is for the GM to get Despair and then spend it. (And, crucially, the GM can't refresh their supply of Despair if they spend Despair to make Pain dominate -- Coins, p.22)

So, besides Pain needing to dominate sometimes because it's the only way the GM has to participate in rolling the dice, it also needs to dominate sometimes because it's the only way PCs are ever going to find Hope.

### Discipline successes are critical.

As in, "critical successes". Discipline is half the size of the maximum Exhaustion and Madness pools that PCs are throwing around. If Discipline manages to dominate, you can think of that as a critical success, as seen in its effects - clear one response, or tick down exhaustion.

That's stuff you'd ordinarily need to spend Hope to do.

So, while Discipline is supposed to represent your character's baseline capabilities, actually having it dominate in a roll is intended to be rare, as seen by the benefits.